# Banner disappears on the Ios in Flutter (Firebase_admob)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, admob

I have the admob plugin installed and it works fine on the android, but on the IOS when switching to another screen and back the banner disappearsenter.

first screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuTFI.png)

go to the second screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVE42.png)

back to the first screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5b10.png)

code for banner:

```
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';

const appId = "ca-app-pub-8525669884798416~3112161926";

class Ads {

  BannerAd bannerAd;

   showBanner() {

   bannerAd ??= createBannerAd();

    bannerAd
      ..load()
      ..show(
        anchorOffset: 0.0,
        anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
      );
  }

  BannerAd createBannerAd() {

    return BannerAd(
      adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
      size: AdSize.fullBanner,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print('BannerAd event $event');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this behavior. I use webView and admob on one screen, Because of this, an incomprehensible conflict occurs on the IOS.
Decision: It is necessary to raise the container webView so that the admob banner does not lie on it